# running multiple websites with different database but using same user database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

Currently I am working working on a project with MySQL RDBMS which contains 5 sites having their own databases. 2 of them are in the same server and the rest of them in different one.

**The 5 sites have different databases.**

I need to make one more database containing only the user login and meta information and direct all 5 sites to that DB while loging in or registering.

Now, the challenge how to organize already registered users.

Users have different permissions set in their respective site.
How do I maintain permission issues for all 5 site since 3 sites contain about 40 permission contents (catalog).

**How do I set 40 permissions to all the users?**

How can I **synchronize** all users from these 5 databases, on two different servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unite all the users in one database and move all access rules from all databases.

**For example**

```
Site1:
User11
User12
...
User1N

AccessRule11
AccessRule12
...
AccessRule1Q

SiteM:
UserM1
UserM2
...
UserMK

AccessRuleM1
AccessRuleM2
...
AccessRuleML


ResultBase:
User11
User12
...
User1N
UserM1
UserM2
...
UserMK

AccessRule11
AccessRule12
...
AccessRule1Q
AccessRuleM1
AccessRuleM2
...
AccessRuleML
```

Later you can normalize the rule set. There maybe the same access rules on different sites. They have to be united.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help you but i will post it. [mysql replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html)